# Nodejs read stdout of some process and do stuff

Tags: node.js, windows, process, stdout

I want to read some stdout of some process with nodejs, in Windows.

So far i got this:

I simulate the process output with :

```
ping -t google.com > ping.txt
```

The ping output is dumped in the ping.txt file.
That file is watched in node for changes.

So, in nodejs i got this code:

```
var filename = 'ping.txt';

var fs = require("fs");

fs.watch(filename, function (event, filename) {
    if (event == 'change') {
        console.log('change', filename);

        fs.stat(filename, function (err, stats) {
            console.log('size ', stats.size);

            if(stats.size > 500){                
                fs.truncate(filename,10,function(){
                    console.log("truncated");
                });

            }            
        })
    }
});
```

But this is my nodejs output:

```
size  0
change ping.txt
size  192
change ping.txt
size  253
change ping.txt
size  375
change ping.txt
size  436
change ping.txt
size  559
truncated
change ping.txt
size  620
truncated
change ping.txt
size  743
truncated
change ping.txt
size  804
truncated
change ping.txt
size  926
truncated
```

The file never gets truncated.

I don't want to get a massive file size, because the real process is getting a lot of output.

So that's the main reason to try to get the file truncated.

But it's not working.

Can anyone give me a hand? This is my first nodejs experiment.

Later i'm planning to output that stdout process trought a websocket, but now i'm stucked with this problem.

Thanks in advance ! Best regards!

**Edit 1:**
The ping process is not the real one that i'm trying to read. The real process is a cryptocoin miner. And it's very resource hungry. 
So that's because i took this aproach. To dump the process output in a file and read it with another process.
I'm not 100% happy to have nodejs managing that cryptocoin process, because i don't know if node can handle it.

If is there a better way to do this, i'm very happy to ear it. Thanks!

Comment: The `ping` process has no way of telling that you've truncated the file, so it will continue to write to where it thinks the end of the file should be.  You can't do it that way.  Surely node.js has a built-in mechanism for piping a child's standard output?

Comment: Thanks Harry, like i said in the comment below, the real process is a cryptocoin miner. And is very resource expensive. I dont know if nodejs can manage it. And i don't want to depend of it. 
That's the reason that took me to think this aproach, of dumping the output to a file and read it with another process. Do you think that is a better aproach? Or a better language to use? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would it make any difference how resource-intensive the child is?  All the parent process has to do is process the output, right?

Answer (score 1):

I did a small snippet using a npm package [rotating-file-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream) and it seems to work:

```
// stream.js
const rfs = require('rotating-file-stream');

const stream = rfs('ping.txt', {
  size: '500B', // rotate every 500 Bytes written
});

const stdin = process.openStdin();

stdin.pipe(stream);
```

Run the command in terminal `ping google.com | node stream.js`

Comment: Yes, i looked this aproach before. But the real process that i'm trying to read the output is a cryptocoin miner.
So it's a very heavy process, vram hungry. 
And i don't want to have to depend on nodejs for it's ejecution.

Comment: Do you think that nodejs can manage a heavy process like that and work like a champ? Or i going to have problems ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Here we are using streams the idea behind streams that it will get chunk of data, bit by bit, so the process will not consume your ram or anything...

In theory node can handle that easily but the reality it's up to you to find out :

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that the only reason the OP is sending the output to a file is that they think (for some reason) that this will be more efficient than sending it to a pipe.  From that perspective, sending it to a pipe that *then* sends it to a file would probably be counter-productive. :-)